# jsPDF-autotable will not show tables side by side

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Trying to display two tables horizontally side by side. The solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686658/jspdf-autotable-how-do-i-display-two-tables-side-by-side-that-span-multiple-pag) SO post works for the poster but does not work for my tables. How can I display the following two tables side by side horizontally? My full code is in [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExddjxR) codepen. Thank you.

// jspdf-autotable code

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

function generatePDF() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('l')
  var startingPage = doc.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber;
  doc.autoTable({ html: '#table1', margin: {right: 30} })
  doc.setPage(startingPage);
  doc.autoTable({ html: '#table2', margin: {left: 30}})
  doc.save('tables.pdf')
}
```

Comment: One (admittedly very ugly) workaround would be to add `startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY - 38,` to your second `autoTable`... Maybe this points you or someone else in the right direction.